# Applying formula every 3rd row in a different column VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I have this formula `=SUM(D4*(K4/100))` I would like to apply in Column M starting at M4 all the way down to last row of data used. How would I achieve this using a macro?

Comment: (a) Create a macro (b) Use a loop (with `Step 3` if your question title is relevant) (c) use the `Formula` or `FormulaR1C1` property of a cell

Comment: Do you need a macro? The body of your question differs from the title, but if you just want it in every row to the last row of data used, you can just double click the bottom right cell with the formula, and it'll automatically fill in all cells until the column next to it runs out of data...

Comment: Yes, I need a macro.

Answer (score 2):

This should do that for you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Every3rdRow()
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Dim lastRow As Integer
  With sht
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim r As Integer
    For r = 4 To lastRow Step 3
       .Cells(r, "M").Formula = "=sum(D" & r & "*(K" & r & "/100))"
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Everything works except I would like the formula to use the cells relative to the row its in. For example: "=sum(D4*(K4/100))" then "=sum(D7*(K7/100))" then "=sum(D10*(K10/100))" and so on.

Comment: @tom, if this answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer. There is a tick mark to the left of the answer.